# Find heart-vector in Einthoven's triangle - a 2D non-orthogonal space

Tags: trigonometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I have a non-orthogonal space defined by vectors $I$ and $III$. These are parallel with two sides of an equilateral triangle, as shown in the picture. On these basis vectors lie vectors $\boldsymbol a$ and $\boldsymbol b$, respectively, whose length is known.

How do I find the (red) vector, from the vectors $\boldsymbol a$ and  $\boldsymbol b$?
[image: sketch of the problem]

---

If it helps, the motivation behind this is to find the so-called heart vector from the [Einthoven's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einthoven%27s_triangle)
[image: einthovens triangle]

Comment: Why do you draw orthogonal lines in a non-orthogonal space? You are supposed to draw lines parallel to the axes I and III.

Comment: @Crostul hm, I am not entirely sure, I might be misunderstanding what the problem is. What I am actually trying to do is find a heart vector from Einthoven's triangle. I have updated the question now.

Comment: A Euclidean vector space can have a non-orthogonal basis. I don't see anything here that even hints at non-Euclidean geometry.

Comment: When you have a geometric vector, as you apparently do here, the addition rule can be represented by a paralellogram. The two vectors to be added are translated so they start at the same point, and they become adjacent sides of the parallelogram. The sum is the diagonal that starts at that same point. It just happens that if the vectors were orthogonal, the parallelogram is that particularly nice kind of parallelogram that we usually call a rectangle.

Comment: @DavidK you're right about the Euclidian geometry, I fixed it now. Thanks. Apropos adding vectors, I actually don't think this is a vector addition anymore (as user Lazy points out in their answer). I need to get the red vector, but I am not sure about the operation.

Comment: I have clarified in the question now, that I am not sure how the operation is called - but it does not seem to be vector addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are not looking for the sum of $a,b$, but for a vector $v$ so that the projection onto $I$ is $a$ and the projection onto $III$ is $b$. In other words: If we assume $I=(1,0)$, $III=(-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2)$ then you want to solve

$$ \langle v, I\rangle = v_1 = \lambda $$
$$ \langle v, III\rangle = -v_1/2 - v_2\sqrt{3}/2 = \mu $$

Then $v_1=\lambda$ and $v_2 = -(\mu+\lambda/2)2/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: You're right, a and b don't seem to be sum to the red vector. I have clarified my question now

Comment: @sjaustirni I think I’ve determined what you want to do, please see if this edit solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that what you want is to follow a method actually used in the
traditional interpretation of electrocardiograms.
I found it explained on page I-3 of
[these instructions](https://www.biopac.com/wp-content/uploads/BSL_l06_BSL_4.pdf),
which match the procedure in your second figure.
This also matches your first figure in the sense that from vectors $a$ and $b$ of certain lengths, both figures produce a new vector of the same length in the same direction.

We can do this the "hard" way or the "easy" way.

The "hard" way is to follow the literal instructions for constructing the final vector. Starting at the origin we plot the Lead I voltage in the horizontal direction to the right. This gives us the coordinates of a point, from which we can find the equation of a vertical line through that point.
Again starting at the origin, we plot the Lead III voltage in the direction downward and to the left, $120^\circ$ from horizontal.
This gives us the coordinates of another point, from which we can find the equation of a line sloping downward to the right at an angle of $30^\circ$ below horizontal through that point.
From the two equations we can compute the point of intersection;
that point is where you put the head of the final vector, and the tail of the final vector is again at the origin,
as in the figure below (copied from the question).

[image: einthovens triangle]

And that's that: you have your vector.

Essentially what this is doing is plotting the two voltages as the two coordinates of a point, except that instead of the two coordinates being plotted on a square grid, they are plotted on an oblique grid like the one shown in the figure below.

[image: einthovens triangle with oblique grid]

Now here's a trick to avoid the whole perpendicular-lines-find-the-equations-and-solve-for-the-intersection business.
The oblique grid in the figure above does not represent coordinates relative to a basis whose vectors are in the direction of the two blue vectors in the figure.
But it *does* represent coordinates relative to a set of basis vectors.
We just have to find the suitable basis vectors.
And those basis vectors are the vectors shown in red in the figure below.
Note that if the markings along the Lead I and Lead III lines are distances from the origin, then the length of each red vector is $1/\cos(30^\circ) = 2/\sqrt3.$

[image]

So the "easy" method is:

- Multiply the red vector at $30^\circ$ below horizontal by the Lead I voltage to get vector $v_1.$
- Multiply the vertical downward red vector by the Lead III voltage to get vector $v_2.$
- Add the two vectors together using standard vector addition: $v = v_1 + v_2.$

Then the resultant vector $v$ is the vector you wanted.